# Can't download file from dropbox

Tags: java, dropbox

I've got a public file storage at dropbox and now I want to download that using java. This is how I did:

```
   String url = "http://www.dropbox.com/s/vk67dz9ca0oqz37/Chrysanthemum.jpg";
        String filename = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\test.jpg";

        try {
            URL download = new URL(url);
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(download.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            fileOut.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
            rbc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But `test.jpg` is invalid. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click on "Download original" in the dropbox page, you can see that it redirects you to http**s**://www.dropbox.com/s/vk67dz9ca0oqz37/Chrysanthemum.jpg?**dl=1**

So, append `?dl=1` to your url and use `https`.

```
String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk67dz9ca0oqz37/Chrysanthemum.jpg?dl=1";
String filename = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\test.jpg";
try {
    URL download = new URL(url);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(download.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    fileOut.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
    rbc.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or, shorter:

```
String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/vk67dz9ca0oqz37/Chrysanthemum.jpg?dl=1";
String filename = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\test.jpg";
try {
    URL download = new URL(url);
    Path fileOut = new File(filename).toPath();
    Files.copy(download.openStream(), fileOut, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```